# How to check if dates in one pandas dataframe fall within ranges of dates in another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, datetime

I have two pandas dataframes.
One is my main file with lots of rows containing "events" such as in the example below, lets call it main_df. While only 2 rows are given, there are around 200.000 in the real file.

| event_nr | date | detail_1 | detail_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| e_0001 | 2010-01-02 07:30:00 | 1 | 100 |
| e_0002 | 2010-06-05 07:30:00 | 0 | 132 |

I then have another df_ranges with date ranges, here also there are a multitude of ranges, albeit not overlapping.

| start | end | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-02-25 | 2010-03-06 | range_1 |
| 2010-06-02 | 2010-06-08 | range_2 |

I now want to check if each date in main_df occurs during any of the time ranges in df_ranges, and if so, create a new column in main_df with the name of the range as a value in the same row.

Desired result:

| event_nr | date | detail_1 | detail_2 | in_range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| e_0001 | 2010-01-02 07:30:00 | 1 | 100 | None |
| e_0002 | 2010-06-05 07:30:00 | 0 | 132 | range_2 |

Most solutions I have encountered only wanted to check if certain dates were between start and end of one single range. I am sure I have to iterate over all ranges and all dates, but don't know how to proceed in practice.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution.

Given the following DataFrames:

```
events = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "event_nr":["e_0001", "e_0002"],
        "date":["2010-01-02 07:30:00", "2010-06-05 07:30:00"]
    }
)


ranges = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "start":["2010-02-25", "2010-06-02"],
        "end":["2010-03-06", "2010-06-08"],
        "range_name":["range_1","range_2"] 
    }
)
```

First, let's make sure all dates are actually datetime objects:

```
events["date"] = pd.to_datetime(events["date"])
ranges["start"] = pd.to_datetime(ranges["start"])
ranges["end"] = pd.to_datetime(ranges["end"])
```

Then, let's make a function that implement the desired selection criteria.

```
def f(row):
    global ranges
    for _i, _row in ranges.iterrows():
        if _row.start <= row.date <= _row.end:
            return _row.range_name
    return None
```

Finally, let's apply the function to the dataframe to generate the desired new column.

```
events["in_range"] = events.apply(f, axis=1)
```

And here is the result:

```
print(events)

  event_nr                date in_range
0   e_0001 2010-01-02 07:30:00     None
1   e_0002 2010-06-05 07:30:00  range_2
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks a lot! It seems to work fine, however, instead of the range name I weirdly get the index of the range (e.g. for range_61 I get 61.0000)

Comment: that is because `_row.name` is actually the index. That is why I have called the column of the ranges dataframe `"range_name"` In this way `return _row.range_name` does actually return what you want. Else, you can keep the column calle `name` and change the return line into `return _row["name"]` without using the dot-notation.